# Kochan's Programming in C Exercise 7.12

Tags: c, arrays

working on Kochans book, and ran into a little difficulty with Exercise 7.12.  The goal is to input a variable length two dimensional array and transpose it.  I've got the transposing part alright, however when i input values into the array, they dont all make it.  The code is below.  Say I specify the array should have two rows, and two column.  and i enter 1,2,3,4.  The return i get is 1,2,3,32.  I think the 32 is just a junk number.  While I suspect there is a problem with my algorithm, I cant figure what it is.  Any insight would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
int Matrix;
int transposedMatrix;
int a;
int b;

printf ("Enter rows\n");
scanf ("%i", &a);
printf ("Enter columns\n");
scanf ("%i", &b);

defineMatrix (a,b);
displayMatrix(a,b);

 return 0;
}

void defineMatrix(a,b)
{
int Matrix[a][b];

int row, column;

for (row = 0; row < a; ++row){
    for (column= 0; column < b; ++column){
       printf ("Enter value");
       scanf ("%i\n", &Matrix[row][column]);
}
}
return 0;
}

void displayMatrix(a,b)

{

int row, column;
int Matrix[a][b];

for (row = 0; row < a; ++row){
    for (column= 0; column <b; ++column)
        printf ("%5i", Matrix[row][column]);

    printf ("\n");

}
}
```

Comment: So the exercise calls for tranposing a matrix to another size, for example a 4x5 matrix will be transposed to a 5x4 matrix.  Though a function cannot return the value, i figured i would transpose and print the matrix within the function, however my output is garbage.  Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you create a matrix called Matrix in defineMatrix. This is private to that function and it gets destroyed when the function completes. Since you want a dynamically sized array things get complicated, the easiest thing to do is to not have those 2 functions. Just put the code inline in main

Comment: although, why would some of the values transfer?  If its destroyed, wouldnt all the values be junk, instead of the ones at the end of the array?

Comment: you are experiencing whats called 'Undefined Behavior'. Anything is possible, what actually happening in your case in the the Matrix in displayMatrix gets allocated in the roughly same place in memory as the first Matrix and so you can see some of the values. Try calling printf("heelo world") between te calls to the defineMAtrix and displayMAtrix calls, that will reuse the same memory and mess it up totally

Answer (score 0):

It's because the array matrix in defineMatrix life is over when the function completes(the stack frame is popped from the stack). In this case if you want to modify an array in another function your function should accept a reference to the array, or to request memory and create matrix from heap with malloc() and return a pointer to it.

Comment: @Jerry Singh thats why i said 'things get complicated'